# Saved EBP is still linked to EBP register?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, buffer-overflow

I am a rookie to reversing, and recently I am working on buffer overflow to understand how it works.

I know that a function is called when you see these in assembly:

```
push ebp             ; Save the caller's ebp
mov ebp, esp         ; Update ebp with current stack frame's esp
```

At first, I guessed that once the caller's ebp was saved on the stack, it would only be changed when you pop it.
After I did some trial and error on buffer overflow, I noticed that if I made a payload (like 77777777\x0e\x86\x04\x08) to cover the saved EIP, the EBP register would also be changed by the payload.

I know that payload will change the values of saved eip and saved caller's ebp on the stack, but how can the ebp register also be changed?
Or the address an entry in stack points to is still linked to the registers themselves?

Comment: Look at the end of the function, just before the `ret`. What do you see? If `ebp` was pushed at the beginning, what is likely to happen at the end?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that leave will also pop ebp, so the saved ebp in scanf was covered by my input and the overflow made changes to it. Thank you for clearing me up.

Answer (score 0):

The registers are not modified when the stored value pointed to by `ebp` is overwritten in a buffer overflow.  Are you sure you are not either: (a) looking at the value of *memory* at the address stored in `ebp`? (b) looking at the value of ebp after a `ret` call?

Comment: I was trying to know what happened before and after scanf if input was very long. I forgot scanf itself would also change ebp and thus it confused me.